# XNA Kinect background removal

Tags: c#, xna, frame, kinect, sensors

I've run into samples for this requirement, but the code I found seems to be deprecated.

Here's the deprecated code I found:
[Kinect background removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107762/kinect-background-removal)

It all uses the obsolete Microsoft.Research.Kinect DLL and the 'Runtime' object. With the current SDK we should use the Microsoft.Kinect DLL.

Does anyone know of a sample that uses the new DLL? I have seen this sample in
http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/kinect-fundamentals-3-getting-data-from-the-depth-sensor/
, but it displays the entire camera frame. Not just the player (without the background).

I've tried to combine that solution with the code from the samples with the obsolete DLL, but have not been successful with the syntax. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of Kinect SDK 1.8 contains a new API for background removal.
I wrote a post about that in my blog
http://edogaru.com/backgroundremoval-api-en-xnamonogame/
(It's in spanish but you can download the source code at the end of the post)

Also, you can look at the samples in Kinect Developer Kit: Coordinate Mapper and combine with XnaBasics

Comment: Glad I checked this. GoogleTranslate helped me get the idea, although your code is pretty clear and self-explanatory. Thank you very much for the help.